# How to clear all the validation errors displayed in the JSP page?

Tags: jsp

I've a view page which looks like:

```
<tr>
    <td align="right"><b>Select your role:</b></td>
    <td align="left">
        <select name="role" id="role" onchange="enableTextBox();">
            <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
            <option value="csc">CSC Employee</option>
        </select><br/>
        <font color=red>
            <form:errors path="role" cssClass="validationError"/>
        </font>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr align=center>
    <td align="right"><b>User ID:</b></td>
    <td align="left">
        <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname" value="" size="15" /><br/>
        <font color="red">
            <form:errors path="uname" cssClass="validationError"/>
        </font>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr align=center>
    <td align="right"><b>Password:</b></td>
    <td align="left">
        <input type=password id="pwd" name="pwd" value="" size="15" /><br/>
        <font color="red">
            <form:errors path="pwd" cssClass="validationError"/>
        </font>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I've validated the page which throws error in red colored font near the input field.
Suppose admin logs in and the error message is displayed after validation. Now, if the admin wants to select "csc employee" from the dropdown list, I need these error messages to be remove and just the input fields should be displayed.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript to clear those form errors using events while typing on those fields...

Comment: could u plz share a snippet like how to do that

Comment: this may help you http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-errors-tag-example/

Answer (score -1):

just remove all these lines `<form:errors path="uname" cssClass="validationError"/>`

Comment: If i remove these lines the validation part will not take place!!

Comment: @lakshmi  use font color same as background color

Comment: if i use the same color as bg, then when i need to display error how can i ??